# SAS: Reading datalines and data from a dataset together in DATA step

Tags: sas

We will be getting a series of high profile order codes during peak hour of the day at 9 am till 10 AM. All the orders are captured into a permanent dataset ORDERS. Now we have to set the priority order to 1 for only the high profile orders.

I am capturing the 5 intervals of an hour and the corresponding high profile code during that hour using below code:

```
data orders; 
input time PROF_CODE $ ;
datalines;
900 A1 
936 R2 
948 BQ 
960 AJ
900 CT 
936 A1 
936 R2 
924 BQ 
900 AJ
912 CT  
;

data profile_orders; 
set orders;
array profile_code {900:960, 5} _temporary_; 
array HPC_CODE{5} $ _temporary_ ('AJ', 'BQ', 'CT', 'A1', 'R2');

do i = 900 to 960 by 12 ;
    do j = 1 to 5 by 1 ;
        if _n_ = 1 then
        input profile_code(i,j) @;
    end;
end;
drop i j; 

datalines;
5 8 3 7 11 
6 44 54 88 1
4 7 3 77 9
3 4 3 4 9 
91 3 8 0 12 
;
```

I have a dataset with order time, code and order details. I have to set the proriry flag only for the orders that came during this time and having the code matching from the permanent dataset and from the datalines above. Can I read the permanent dataset from the above data step itself along with the datalines? This order of codes changes everyday which we get in email. So we want to read the codes from datalines only.

Array values: 
profile_code --> (900,1) :5, (900,2) : 8, (900,3) :3, (900,4) : 7, (900,5) :11
         (912,1) :6, (912,2) : 44, (912,3) :54, (912,4) : 88, (912,5) :1
         (924,1) :4, (924,2) : 7, (924,3) :3, (924,4) : 77, (924,5) :9
         (936,1) :3, (936,2) : 4, (936,3) :3, (936,4) : 4, (936,5) :9
         (948,1) :91, (948,2) : 3, (948,3) :8, (948,4) : 0, (948,5) :12

Expected output:

910 A1 7
936 R2 9
948 BQ 4
960 AJ .
.
.

(I have rounded the time intervals to the nearest 12th minute interval in the input dataset orders).

Comment: Simply put, my question is, can I read a permanent dataset and datalines from the same DATA step?

Comment: Yes, you can read a permanent dataset and datalines from the same data step.

Comment: @reeza, could you please provide any samples?

Comment: You don't show a set statement so I'm not sure what you're trying to do overall though.  But to answer your question in the comments, yes you can. Will that do what you want, I'm not sure.

Comment: If you provide an example of what you want the final dataset to look like, people will be able to advise how best to construct it.

Comment: @user667489 yeah, I can understand. Now I tried my level best to ask the question in proper lines. If this does not work out, I will change the way I implement the requirement.

Comment: Your requirements are still not clear from what you've written. E.g. you say you want to show 11 orders for code A1 at time 910 but the array you've produced has no corresponding element for that order at time 910. Please post some datalines containing the exact output you want to produce from your example inputs and explain the logic you want to use to generate it.

Comment: If you look at the permanent dataset first record we received a distinct  order at 9:00 am for customer A1 code which is equivalent to j=4. As this is within timeline 9:00 and 9:12 we have to consider count from datalines as 7

Comment: Usually we get the time as 901 for 9:01 which can be rounded as 9 AM. 9:15 to 9:12 like that. To the nearest 12th minute interval.

Comment: I don't think you can selectively read points like that...

Answer (score 1):

This will read datelines and the dataset, however the output may not be what you want.

```
data want;
set sashelp.class;
input name2 $ age2;
cards;
Sigma 13
Beta 14
Alpha 18
;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Reeza. Here it is working. In my requirement, I have to read the dataset to retrieve the corresponding orders passed in the datalines for the corresponding timeframe and the high profile customer code. In which case I am not able to read the dataset, when I put the set statement, profile_orders is coming empty. Updated the code in my question. My desired output is to retrieve the counts like: 910 A1 has 11 orders which is by reading 5th element from first row of datalines --> 5 8 3 7 11